# Dragger with collider on Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I´m making a simple CAD application on Unity 3D using C# to configure closets. I'm trying to limit the movement of the shelves so you can move them only on the hole, so I have a dragger attached to every piece of the closet I want to move, but obviously they can cross with each other.

I thought I could use the collider system that Unity has to limit this movement but since I never worked with Unity before I´m kinda lost. This is my dragger so far:

```
mousePosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, cubo_tmp.transform.position.y, distance);
        objPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
        objPosition.Set(objPosition.x, cubo_tmp.transform.position.y, cubo_tmp.transform.position.z);
```

I keep y and z components so it can move only in one direction.

Answer (score 1):

Box Colliders are best for cuboid shaped objects.

In the editor, if you click GameObject > 3d Object > Cube, Unity will add a cube with a Box Collider to your scene:

If you want to add a Box Collider to a GameObject that doesn't have one, click Add Component in the Inspector panel and type in "Box Collider" to find it. It looks like this:

[image: Box Collider]

Note: If the `IsTrigger` box is checked, the Collider acts as a Trigger rather than  a Collider.

A GameObject with a Collider will "collide" with any other GameObject that also has a Collider, with a small exception involving 2 Mesh Colliders that are both set to Convex.

**EDIT:** I think you are able to intersect the objects because you are modifying Transform.position directly in your code. This might override the collision behaviour.

Also Go to Edit > Project Settings > Physics and make sure your layer collision matrix allows collisions for the layers on which your objects are placed.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already got every GameObject with a Box Collider attached but i can still move the shelves to make them cross with each other. ¿ Is there any event that triggers when a collision happens?